# How do I use "button_to" to update a boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, boolean

Preface:  I'm still a beginner to web development, let alone rails so I'm constantly in over my head.

In my rails application, I have a boolean called "accepted" in "Bids."

On the show page for Bids, I am trying to create a `button_to` called "Accept Bid" that will, obviously, update the boolean from false to true, and then later, I will make it do a few other things.  I experimented a bit with this but ended up getting so confused, I thought I would come here for some inspiration/push in the right direction.

Here's my bid.rb

```
    class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :swarm_request

  # Accepts a bid for a swarm request
  def accept!
    self.swarm_request.update_attributes(:accepted => true)
    # also update the bid with any details here?
  end


end
```

Am I on the right track with this?  Or should I create an action in the bids controller instead?  Is using button_to the best way to do this?  My apologies if I'm using incorrect jargon, or not being clear enough.  Like I said, newb.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's ok to have skinny controller and fat model. you can read about this at http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model
and i don't see anything wrong with `button_to` for this job.

Comment: thanks for the link, that clears some very basic stuff up for me that has been in the back of my mind.  I hate to ask for someone to write code for me, but how would you code the button_to statement?  I'm having trouble understanding what ":action => ?" should be.  I need to call the accept! method on bid, right?

Comment: You have to write `BidsController` with some action at first. and then write `<%= button_to "Some_title", :controller => "bids", :action => "some_action" %>` ( or link_to ) in your view. but all these params depends on you apps and I know nothing about your application. just start from [http://guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) these guides and move on. You can't write something without reading some docks or books about rails

Comment: Well I was wondering if I should just move my accept! into the controller instead of the model, since button_to wants an action.  It's clear I need to stop and do some more research, so thanks for doing what you could with what I gave you.  ;)